# I am not having a response for my question

Tags: discussion

No comments, no edits, no answers. How can I show up my question to potential users and get responses?

[Link for my Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/216482/154486)

Comment: Have you looked at [what should I do if no one answers my question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) in the help center?

Comment: Nope, let me try

Comment: Also see [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer) on the main network meta.